# Jest tests failing on d3 import

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, jestjs

I'm running the test

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import MyComponent from '../../../../components/MyComponent';

test('renders MyComponent', () => {
  render(<MyComponent />);
});
```

on a React app component using d3 with imports as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

using the command

```
react-scripts test
```

This yields an error on the d3 import:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/Users/wogsland/Projects/sepia/node_modules/d3/src/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from "d3-array";
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

What am I missing? The component works fine in the browser, it just fails on the most basic of tests.

Comment: You need to create a minimal, reproducible example. It works fine for me, see https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-buck-vdsiy?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the tip from Tiep Phan's answer I added the following to my package.json file:

```
"jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/(?!d3|d3-array|internmap|delaunator|robust-predicates)"]
},
```

Answer (score 11):

> To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.

From the above suggestions, we can tell Jest not to parse ES modules in `node_modules`.

In your `jest.config.js` file, you can add the following lines. You can add any ES module you want to the array.

```js
const esModules = ['d3', 'd3-array', 'other-d3-module-if-needed'].join('|');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!${esModules})`],
  // ...
};
```

Comment: I still get this error: \node_modules\d3\src\index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from "d3-array";
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Comment: if you're using d3 v7, you might need to downgrade to v6. or add few more config to babel

Comment: I actually was only missing "allowJs": true in tsconfig.json

Comment: If you use d3 in a project handled by Create React App, you have to use Jest config in `package.json` as proposed by [wogsland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3704831/wogsland)

Comment: I found I needed to add all of the following `delaunator|d3-delaunay|robust-predicates|internmap|d3|d3-array`

Answer (score 7):

For D3v7 You can add `moduleNameMapper` in jest like so:

```
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "d3": "<rootDir>/node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js",
      "^d3-(.*)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/d3-$1/dist/d3-$1.min.js"
    }
```

Comment: When using jest with Visx 3+ the "d3" entry wasn't necessary for me.  Only adding this comment in case it helps others:  
"moduleNameMapper": { "^d3-(.*)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/d3-$1/dist/d3-$1.min.js"}

Answer (score 1):

I fast way to solve it is to include

```
jest.mock('d3-color', () => ({}));
```

in your tests (this works if you aren't actually testing the d3 functionality) and just want the error to stop blocking the actual tests